# Кластеризация на базе Windows Server 2008r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Коллеги, недавно столкнулся с задачей - объединить несколько неплохих физических машин в одну мощную, поводом тому послужил приказ начальства. Бюджет фирмы не позволял купить мощную серверную машины, а шеф так и сказал: "Я где-то читал, что так можно, говорят это облако, выполняй" - по отдельности каждая машина не особо со временем справлялась со своими задачами, а вот вместе очень даже может быть.Итак, я прошу помощи и совета, с чего начать,куда копать и что конкретно мне гуглить и какое оборудование мне для этого понадобится.Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Какие сервисы у вас будут работать, web, база данных, маршрутизатор , что?

Comment: Терминальный сервер.

Comment: Но это не кластер! Потому, что:[quote] Remote Desktop Connection Manager is actually not cluster-specific, but it allows you to logically group server remote desktop connections – ideal if you are working with clusters for easy access to all the nodes within the cluster.[\qouote]

Answer (score 1):

Так это вам через Hyper-V и Failover! Вот тут у Мелкомягких есть инфа: http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc732181(v=ws.10).aspx